# make sticky header without custom js code

Tags: magento-2.1, theme, jquery

I tried to make the header sticky using the default jquery code:

```
    $('.page-header').mage('sticky', {
    container: '.page-wrapper'
});
```

I added this piece of code into the `theme.js` file in the `web/js` directory.
It doesn't work, how to fix that?

Here the complete `theme.js` code:

```
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
define([
    'jquery',
    'mage/smart-keyboard-handler',
    'mage/mage',
    'mage/ie-class-fixer',
    'domReady!'
], function ($, keyboardHandler) {
    'use strict';

    if ($('body').hasClass('checkout-cart-index')) {
        if ($('#co-shipping-method-form .fieldset.rates').length > 0 && $('#co-shipping-method-form .fieldset.rates :checked').length === 0) {
            $('#block-shipping').on('collapsiblecreate', function () {
                $('#block-shipping').collapsible('forceActivate');
            });
        }
    }

    $('.cart-summary').mage('sticky', {
        container: '#maincontent'
    });

    $('.page-header').mage('sticky', {
        container: '.page-wrapper'
    });

    $('.panel.header > .header.links').clone().appendTo('#store\\.links');

    keyboardHandler.apply();
});
```

UPDATE
I created a `sticky.js` file inside `web/js` directory and put the following code:

```
require([
    'jquery', 
    'mage/mage', 
    'domReady!'
], function ($) {
    $('.page-header').mage('sticky', {
        container: '.page-wrapper',
        spacingTop: 0
    });
});
```

I loaded this file in the default.xml:

```
<head>  
    <link src="js/sticky.js"/>    
</head>
```

It doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting it inside the **`document.ready()`** function

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'mage/smart-keyboard-handler',
    'mage/mage',
    'mage/ie-class-fixer',
    'domReady!'
], function ($, keyboardHandler) {
    'use strict';
    $(document).ready(function(){
    if ($('body').hasClass('checkout-cart-index')) {
        if ($('#co-shipping-method-form .fieldset.rates').length > 0 && $('#co-shipping-method-form .fieldset.rates :checked').length === 0) {
            $('#block-shipping').on('collapsiblecreate', function () {
                $('#block-shipping').collapsible('forceActivate');
            });
        }
    }

    $('.cart-summary').mage('sticky', {
        container: '#maincontent'
    });

    $('.page-header').mage('sticky', {
        container: '.page-wrapper'
    });

    $('.panel.header > .header.links').clone().appendTo('#store\\.links');

    keyboardHandler.apply();
    });
});
```